# MPS Template use of parameter

Tags: mps

In MPS I have defined a template:

```
template reduce_Car
Input Car

parameters
color : String

<TF [<Car>???</Car>] TF>
```

Now I wanted to use the defined parameter "color" in my template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access parameters through genContext. So wrap the text to replace with a property macro

<TF [<Car>$[red]</Car>] TF>

and down in the Inspector for the property macro access the parameter as 'genContext.color'